# jquery load - not able to run the javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I am using jquery ui dialog. In that dialog box, a php file(ex:test.php) is getting loaded using ajax call. Inside the test.php file, it contains some javascript code.

The problem is, after loading the test.php file in to jquery ui dialog, the javascript code inside the test.php file are not getting loaded. Any idea to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If it is pure inline JavaScript, it should be executed. Does it implement `$(document).ready()`? In that case the JavaScript will not be executed because the event will never fire. Also be sure your JavaScript code comes after all HTML to allow your script to find the HTML elements.